# Showing output in a certain way

Tags: c

I am trying to print out the ASCII values of all the characters in a text file.

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
        FILE *fp;
        int c;
        fp = fopen(argv[1], "r");
        while((c = fgetc(fp)) != EOF) {
                printf("%c %3d\n", c, (int)c);
        }
        fclose(fp);
        return 0;
}
```

Is it possible to show the output as shown below?

```
r     a     n     d     o     m
114   97   110   100   111   109
```

Assuming the first word in my input file is 'random'. Thanks

Comment: Yes, it's possible.  What have you tried so far and why did it not work?

Comment: How many characters across do you want?  Do you really want the spacing as shown, with 3 blanks between the digit sequences in the second line, and all except the first character of the first line aligned over the second digit?  Why the erratic layout?  What should happen with control characters like newlines and tabs (some of which have single-digit values)?  How wide should the code assume the output lines are?  Your output format is sloppily presented and underspecified.

Comment: I am assuming the input file will have a maximum 1000 characters. I need the ASCII value below the character in a readable form.

Comment: So, you want up to 1000 characters worth of input presented on two potentially very long output lines?  It is doable; it is not clear that it is desirable.  You've not addressed my other questions (in fact, size of file wasn't a question).

Answer (score 2):

Yes, as [hexiecs](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6549517/hexiecs) said, it is very possible.  Asking *how* would be a much better question.  I am going to assume this is what you mean.

Here is an example of how you might go about doing this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define NEW_TERMINAL_LINE 10

void print_current_characters(char char_equivalents[]);

int main(int argc, char const *argv[]) {
  char char_equivalents[NEW_TERMINAL_LINE] = {0};

  int c;
  int i = 0;
  int final_position; /* Store the final position that we will use later
                       * to get the remaining characters in the buffer */

  FILE *file;
  file = fopen("file.txt", "r");
  if (file) {
    while ((c = getc(file)) != EOF) {
        if (i > NEW_TERMINAL_LINE - 1) {
          /* Every time the buffer fills up, we need to go to a new line
           * in the output as well (defined by NEW_TERMINAL_LINE).
           * Then we need to clear the buffer and make a new line 
           * to start off printing again!
          */
          print_current_characters(char_equivalents);
          int j;
          for (j = 0; j < sizeof(char_equivalents)/sizeof(char_equivalents[0]); j++) {
            char_equivalents[j] = 0; /* Clear the filled up buffer */
            i = 0;
          }
          printf("\n\n");
        }
        /* Print the character itself (we will print the ASCII when the buffer fills up) */
        char_equivalents[i] = c;
        if(char_equivalents[i] == '\n') {
          printf("\\n\t");
        } else if (char_equivalents[i] == '\t') {
          printf("\\t\t");
        } else if (char_equivalents[i] == ' ') {
          printf("[space]\t");
        } else {
          printf("%c\t", c);
        }
        final_position = i;
        i++;
    }

    /* Print any remaining characters in the buffer */
    print_current_characters(char_equivalents);

    fclose(file);
  }
  printf("\n");
  return 0;
}
void print_current_characters(char char_equivalents[]) {
  printf("\n");
  int i;

  for(i = 0; i < NEW_TERMINAL_LINE; i++) {
    if (char_equivalents[i] == 0 || NULL) {
      break; /* Don't print if there is nothing but 0s in the buffer */
    }
    if(char_equivalents[i] == '\n') {
      printf("\\n\t\t");
    } else if (char_equivalents[i] == '\t') {
      printf("\\t\t");
    } else {
      printf("%d\t", (int)char_equivalents[i]); /* Print the ASCII character */
    }
  }
}
```

With my previous edit, [Jonathan Leffler](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15168/jonathan-leffler) and I were discussing what would happen if the buffer filled up since the original poster said in a comment:

> I am assuming the input file will have a maximum 1000 characters.

The output would be a *very* long line unless there were newlines after a certain amount of characters.

We could just have an array with a maximum buffer of 1000, but we could also save more memory by just processing the file every `x` amount of characters.  Here, after every `NEW_TERMINAL_LINE` number of characters, we can create a new line and print out the current buffer.  Finally we can empty the buffer, and continue processing the characters.  In fact, using this approach, *the buffer is only limited by the available memory on the computer*.

Say we want the maximum number of characters (and the corresponding ASCII values) on a line to be displayed as 10.  The text file contains the string: `random random random random random random random random [enter]` (Hypothetically, the string could be *much* longer and the program would still display it neatly).  The output of this program looks like<sup>1</sup>:

```
r   a   n   d   o   m   [space] r   a   n   
114 97  110 100 111 109 32     114  97  110 

d   o   m   [space] r   a   n   d   o   m   
100 111 109 32     114  97  110 100 111 109 

[space] r   a   n   d   o   m   [space] r   a   
32     114  97  110 100 111 109 32     114  97  

n   d   o   m   [space] r   a   n   d   o   
110 100 111 109 32     114  97  110 100 111 

m   [space] r   a   n   d   o   m   [space] r   
109 32     114  97  110 100 111 109 32     114  

a   n   d   o   m   \n  
97  110 100 111 109 \n
```

if `NEW_TERMINAL_LINE` is set to `10`.

1. We end up storing the ASCII equivalents in an array named `char_equivalents`.  For every character we come across, we store it in the array, and then we print it out followed by a tab.
2. Once the buffer array is full, we move down a line, loop through the array, and print out the ASCII values with formatting:

   Since `char`s are essentially `int`s in disguise as ASCII, we simply typecast the `char` as an `int`.  This will print out the corresponding ASCII value.  Afterwards, we add a tab to make sure everything aligned with the line above. With this information, it is not difficult to loop through the array and print out the corresponding information.
3. We finally reset the buffer, and print the blank new line seen after `NEW_TERMINAL_LINE` characters for clarity.
4. The buffer is filled and reset until we have printed all of the characters in the file (the previous steps are repeated).
5. In the end, sometimes the buffer isn't full so we never printed out the remaining ASCII equivalents for the last line in the output.  We simply call `print_current_characters()` again.

---

<sup>1</sup> I don't really think this was the best way to format the code, but at the same time, I did want to honor the format that the [original post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38711239/showing-output-in-a-certain-way) asked for.

Comment: What will your code do with a newline or tab character in the file?  What will happen when the file contains 24 characters?  Methinks the second loop will be printing too much data.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I suppose I could edit and handle the special cases of a newline or tab character.  I did mention that the `MAX_CHAR_LINE_LEN` is certainly a limitation, however it is just as easy to increase the buffer to 100/ a more reasonable amount.

Comment: My concern about the printing is that if you have 24 characters in the input, then the first line's worth of characters will be 20 long, so when processing the last 4 characters, the second loop will quietly print 20 characters again — the last 4 from the file and the 16 left over from the previous line.  You need to limit that second loop to the number of characters read into the buffer this time (not the buffer size and character non-zero). The printing of control characters will probably screw up the layout, but you could defend yourself with "the question doesn't say what to do with them".

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I really appreciate your feedback on this.  Say, in my `while` loop, I added a statement to exit and print an error if `i` is over 19 (the line will have been to long).  Do you think doing this will fix the issue?

Comment: There's a comment from the OP that file might be up to 1000 characters long.  That comment doesn't address all my questions, but we'll wangle the answers one step at a time.  Assuming that you are going to process up to 20 characters of input per line of output (which might require a 160-column terminal, but that's doable), then you need to revise the first loop to terminate when the buffer is full.  You then print the data in two lines; then you go back and refill the buffer and repeat.  Just make sure you know how many characters were read into the buffer this time.

Comment: So, read up to 20 characters; print up to 20 characters over two lines of output; repeat until there's no more data to read.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Wait, why not just make the buffer less than 1000 then (I just saw the comment)?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/118860/discussion-between-jonathan-leffler-and-irove).

Answer (score 1):

It will become more convenient if you process individual words instead of each characters. This way you can print each individual characters of the words first, and then print ASCII values of each characters the words next.

You can do try something like this.

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    FILE *fp;
    int c;
    char line[100];  /* Buffer to hold each line */
    fp = fopen(argv[1], "r");
    /* get each line, and print each word of the line */
    while (fgets(line, 100, fp) != NULL) {
            line[strlen(line) - 1] = '\0';
            print_words(line);
    }
    fclose(fp);
    return 0;
}

/* print_words: print each word from line */
void print_words(char *line)
{
    char *word;

    /* get each word, and print them with ascii values */
    if ((word = strtok(line, " ")) != NULL)
            ascii_print(word);
    while ((word = strtok(NULL, " ")) != NULL)
            ascii_print(word);
}

/* ascii_print: print each char and its ascii values for a word*/
void ascii_print(char *word)
{
    int i, len;

    len = strlen(word);

    /* print the word */
    for(i = 0; i < len; i++)
            printf("%-4c", word[i]);
    printf("\n");

    /* print ascii values */
    for(i = 0; i < len; i++)
            printf("%-4d", word[i]);
    printf("\n");
}
```

---

Note that above program is not totally correct, and may produce buggy results in some test cases. However it shows the idea that it is easier if you process word by word, instead of character by character.

Although, the code is simple, you may have to see manual pages of `fgets()` and `strtok()` if you are not familiar with them.

Briefly saying, `fgets()` gets a `line` from a file, and `strtok()` gets each `word` from a line. For more info, you need to do `man 3 strtok` and `man 3 fgets` in Google (or in command line if using Unix-like machine).

Comment: Why is it more convenient to process words than characters?  What is there about the output format that suggests that?  Granted, the output format is under-specified, but I'm not following the logic of your opening statement.

Comment: You made me rethink. My logic was as that the programmer had to store the printed characters in some sort of buffer to print the ascii values of those characters in second line, so it would be convinient to capture each words using standard library `strtok` instead of adding the characters into the buffer using assignment.

Answer (score 0):

You can first use a buffer to record the input in a line, then you can show the ASCII values of the input by transferring the characters in the buffer to integers in the following line.